# Unable to retrieve user id when creating a new account

Tags: javascript, meteor

I do not know why I unable to retrieve user id when creating a new account and add a role for this user.

methods.js  :methods for update and insert new account driver with which I would assign the roles 'driver' for every new account ,registering a new account is going successfully, but the addition of a role does not work

```
    import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
    import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';
    import { CONST } from '../../common/constants.js';
    import { Roles } from 'meteor/alanning:roles';

    Meteor.methods({
      updateUserProfile: (newProfile) => {
        const userId = Meteor.userId();
        // var isEmailChanged = currentProfile ?
        //     newProfile.email != currentProfile.email :

        Meteor.users.update(userId, {
          $set: {
            profile: newProfile,
          },
        }, {
          validationContext: 'updateUserProfile',
        });


      },

      createDriver: (newUser) => {
        var id =Accounts.createUser({
          username: newUser.username,
          email: newUser.email,
          password: newUser.password,
          profile: newUser.profile,
         roles: CONST.USER_ROLES.DRIVER,
        });
        //console.log(Meteor.userId());
         Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, roles);
      },
    });
```

Driver-join.js

```
Meteor.call('createDriver', data, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        Session.set(SESSION.ERROR, error);
      } else {
        FlowRouter.go('/s/driver/vehicles');  // TODO : replace with redirection by root name
      }
    });
```

roles

```
    roles: {
    type: [String],
    optional: true,
    allowedValues: [CONST.USER_ROLES.CLIENT, CONST.USER_ROLES.DRIVER, CONST.USER_ROLES.ADMIN],
    defaultValue: CONST.USER_ROLES.CLIENT,
  },
```

Comment: can you post the Accounts.createUser code? (I guess its your code, not some framework..).. maybe it takes time to create the user (maybe its asynchronous action? not very skilled at javascript though..).. try to add some sleep after the user creation..

Comment: Are you running this code on the server? Note that the `roles` attribute will be ignored by default.

Comment: yes i running code on the server side

Comment: And what makes you think that you are not getting the `id` correctly? I think that issue is with the way you are trying to add the roles and not with the `id` (where are `roles` defined?).

Answer (score 0):

What if add this to the server?

```
Meteor.users.after.insert(function (userId, doc) {
   Roles.addUsersToRoles(doc._id, [CONST.USER_ROLES.DRIVER])
});
```

Also remove roles property when you add new user, it doesn't work.

But your code should work as well. What is the roles in `Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, roles);`?